# CAS Retrieve user attributes after log in

Tags: cas

CAS can push the logged in user attributes to the client when using the SAML ticket validation. But if I use OAuth, is there another way that I can retrieve user attributes through a second call to the CAS server using the received accessToken? I think this should be possible as when a user is authenticated(eg. through facebook) the requested attributes are in CAS memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible as the user's attributes are indeed stored in the CAS server. As explained in the documentation: `https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+client+support+in+CAS+server+version+%3E%3D+3.5.1`, you can define what OAuth attributes you want to retrieve exactly like for any other *attribute repository*. You can even recreate the user's profile on the CAS client application side.
Here is a working example: `https://github.com/leleuj/cas-oauth-demo-3.5.x/blob/master/cas-oauth-client-demo-3.5.x/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml`. You can also get the OAuth access token to perform additionnal operations...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not sure whether this is the right answer. I want the CAS to act as an oAuth server for my client applications. The client applications will issue /oauth2.0/authorize request and the CAS will handle the login process. Then I want those client applications to retrieve profile info without using SAML. The documentation says "On CAS client side, to receive attributes, you need to use SAML validation or a customized CAS validation." So how we use OAuth and SAML together in that case? In fact I'm evaluating 4.0.0.0RC2

Comment: "On CAS client side, to receive attributes, you need to use SAML validation or a customized CAS validation." comes from the documentation to bring OAuth client support to the CAS server. The right documentation you're looking for is : https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuration+for+the+OAuth+server+support... and there is a /profile url to retrieve the user's profile...

Comment: This is great. When the  CAS server is configured for OAuth as per your link, it works great. I used `SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler` and when issue the /oauth2.0/profile it gives few attributes.

Comment: The next thing is I need the users to log in by clicking the facebook login link. That means the CAS sever should be configured as oauth server as well as oauth client for facebook. When I do this and when I log in through the facebook login link, the page is not redirected to the client app. It displays "CAS is Unavailable" page and it throws `ERROR [org.jasig.cas.support.oauth.web.OAuth20CallbackAuthorizeController] - <oauth20_callbackUrl is missing from the session and can not be retrieved.` what could be the reason

Comment: Strange ! After a successful authentication at Facebook, you should be redirected to the original provided service. The OAuth20CallbackAuthorizeController is requested only on a /oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize url : it should never be called in that case...

Comment: Well this is what is happening. If I just log in using the username=password, then after successful authentication CAS is redirected to `oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?ticket=ST......` once I click the authorize link the page will be redirected to the service page. But when login through facebook CAS will again redirected to the `oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize?ticket=ST......` but this time it will show the error page. Can we eliminate this oauth2.0/callbackAuthorize altogether and make CAS redirect to the service page directly?

Comment: What is the lifetime set for your service tickets ? Would you mind asking this question on the CAS user mailing list : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/jasig-cas-user ? It would be easier...